# Simplificar comparação de valor em um input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um `input` no meu formulário com `id="nome"`:

```
<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" />
```

Gostaria que o valor desse `input` fosse igual a: "jose", "maria" ou "joao".

Eu tenho a seguinte função para verificar se o valor da `input` coincide com um dos nomes acima:

```
function valida(){
    campo = $("#nome");
    if(campo.val() == "jose" || campo.val() == "maria" || campo.val() == "joao")
    {
        alert("Nome válido!");
    }else{
        alert("Nome inválido!");
    }
}
```

É possível, em vez de repetir `campo.val() == "NOME" ||...` para cada nome, fazer uma comparação mais simplificada, sem ter que ficar repetindo `campo.val() ==` para cada nome apenas no `if`, sem usar array ou outro subterfúgio fora da função?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma boa forma de fazer essa comparação é com *array* mesmo, mas já que não quer acredito que a segunda opção seja por expressão regular.

```js
function valida(){
  campo = $("#nome");
  if(campo.val().match(/^(joao|jose|maria)$/))
  {
    alert("Nome válido!");
  } else {
    alert("Nome inválido!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" onchange="valida()" />
```

Dá uma olhada nesse [site](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/03/14/better-ways-of-comparing-a-javascript-string-to-multiple-values/).

Comment: Show de bola! Obg!

Answer (score 2):

Isso deve resolver seu problema:

```
var nomes = ["Everton", "Joao", "Rodrigo"];
var campo = $("#nome");
if (nomes.indexOf(campo.val()) > -1) {
   alert("Encontrou");
} else {
   alert("Não encontrou");
}
```

Comment: Não gostaria de usar array pra isso. Gostaria de um modo simplificado de comparação no if.